# using applications from one linux flavor to another on same pc

Tags: virtualbox

I have zorin OS alongside ubuntu on my laptop. Virtualbox is installed on Zorin, I did it from terminal completely. Now, is there any way I can use that same Virtualbox on Ubuntu?
Thanks in advance :)

ps: Ubuntu 14.04 is my OS version.
Please keep your answers simple, I may have difficulty grasping them as I'm new to the world of computers.

Comment: For those wondering what Zorin is, it's an OS based on Ubuntu.

Comment: @user3209333 Is your goal to use the same VirtualBox installation... or is your goal use the same *guests* (i.e., virtual machines) on both host OSes?

Answer (score 1):

In general it is not a good idea to share application from one Linux flavor to the other.

Even if both flavors were base on Ubuntu we can not rely on all **shared libraries** being installed, or have the version needed for a given application. It may work fine but in case there are issues we are faced with a confusing and hard to debug situation.

In addition, most applications heavily depend on libraries that had already been installed by the distribution. The **benefit** from sharing application binaries would be rather minimal.

Only rarely a **self contained application** binary compiled for the same architecture may successfully be shared (this may e.g. be the case for proprietary software or some games).

Even sharing application's **settings** from our HOME may cause trouble if the distributions came with different application versions that may have a differing settings format.

The **Virtual Box** application should not be shared between distributions, as it depends on at least one **kernel module** loaded at boot. But of course you can easily share the virtual machines without issue, provided they are accesible from and registered in the corresponding Virtual Box installation.

Comment: That was enlightening..!
thanks :)
I've listened to you and downloaded virtualbox separately for ubuntu too..